# Try and Catch on TSQL - catch not catching

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, try-catch

I have a stored procedure that seems not to be logging its errors correctly.

The code is erroring, but the catch block doesn't seem to be coming into effect.

The try block is fairly long - but the erroring section is simple and comes rightat the end, so I've precis'd that.

```
BEGIN TRY 
insert into tbl_X
select * from #temp_tbl_Y

RETURN 1
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    Insert Into ExtractsErrorLog
    SELECT 
    getdate() as ErrorDate 
    ,object_name(@@procid) as ProcedureName
    ,ERROR_NUMBER() as ErrorNumber
    ,ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage
    ;
DECLARE @errormessage as varchar(max);
DECLARE @errorseverity as int;
DECLARE @errorstate as int;

set @errormessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
set @errorseverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
set @errorstate = ERROR_STATE();

 RAISERROR (@errormessage,
            @errorseverity,
            @errorstate
               );


END CATCH;
```

The error the proc is failing on is our old friend
"Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."
I've fixed that error - It was a dumb lazy mistake - but  I'm baffled why my error logging process didn't seem to be working - no row is being  inserted into my ExtractsErrorLog table.

Comment: It's a compile time error, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286667/sql-try-catch-statement-not-handling-error-sql-server-2008

Comment: Can you post the table definition of `ExtractsErrorLog`?

Comment: Thanks Ivan - that makes a lot of sense - and that thread offers a workaround too. Sorry to have missed it and reposted. I'd read that catch didn't catch compile - but I hadn't twigged that this would be a compile error. 
Does anyone know if there's a guide online to understanding what errors occur at compile/recompile. I can see why this would be one now, and I suppose missing tables etc. too? But I'd like to be certain and I've not had much look finding details on this.

Comment: @DanBennett, did you figure out a workaround for this?  I'm expecting this error and wanting to TRY|CATCH it to run different logic when it occurs - the work around is just moving the error to the inner SP call.

Comment: Hi @ColinMac - see the link in Ivan G's message, it points to resources, some of which point to options. We didn't pursue this in the end because we felt that the options for capturing the error added man hours code complexity which outweighed the benefit.YMMV

Comment: The compile time error doesn't occur if the inner-sp call is just a simple select statement.  Then the top-layer SP runs and gets the error when it realizes that the SP-select statement has a changed table definition, and the catch worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TSQL's `TRY...CATCH` does not catch that error.  This error falls into the "compilation/recompilation" type errors that are not handled by the `CATCH` block "within the same level of execution".

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx):

> The following types of errors are not handled by a CATCH block when
>   they occur at the same level of execution as the TRY…CATCH construct:
>
> - Compile errors, such as syntax errors, that prevent a batch from
>     running.
> - Errors that occur during statement-level recompilation, such
>     as object name resolution errors that occur after compilation because
>     of deferred name resolution

...

> You can use TRY…CATCH to handle errors that occur during compilation
>   or statement-level recompilation by executing the error-generating
>   code in a separate batch within the TRY block. For example, you do
>   this by placing the code in a stored procedure or by executing a
>   dynamic Transact-SQL statement using sp_executesql. This allows
>   TRY…CATCH to catch the error at a higher level of execution than the
>   error occurrence. For example, the following code shows a stored
>   procedure that generates an object name resolution error. The batch
>   that contains the TRY…CATCH construct is executing at a higher level
>   than the stored procedure; and the error, which occurs at a lower
>   level, is caught.

I ran into similar issues with a script creating a transaction inside a `TRY...CATCH` that would  `ROLLBACK` the transaction if it failed.  A statement inside the transaction was throwing that same error and caused the transaction to never be closed, as the `CATCH` was never entered.

As mentioned in the MSDN article, one alternative is to create a stored procedure out of your `INSERT` statement and then call that inside your try/catch.  If the sproc is wrong, you'll catch the compilation error while trying to create it.  If the table definition later changes to invalidate the sproc, then the `TRY...CATCH` will catch the exception for you.

If you want it to all live in one script, you can make it a [temporary stored procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669(v=sql.105).aspx/#sectionToggle1), but you will then need to handle the compilation errors while you are creating the sprocs.  It's not pretty, but it will work:

```
-- Creating error sproc to re-use code
CREATE PROCEDURE #HandleError AS
    Insert Into ExtractsErrorLog
    SELECT  GETDATE() as ErrorDate 
            ,object_name(@@procid) as ProcedureName
            ,ERROR_NUMBER() as ErrorNumber
            ,ERROR_LINE() as ErrorLine
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMessage;

    DECLARE @errormessage as varchar(max);
    DECLARE @errorseverity as int;
    DECLARE @errorstate as int;

    set @errormessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    set @errorseverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
    set @errorstate = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR ( @errormessage,
                @errorseverity,
                @errorstate);
GO

-- Create a stored procedure of our INSERT and catch any compilation errors
CREATE PROCEDURE #TEST AS
    insert into tbl_X
    select * from #temp_tbl_Y
GO
IF (@@ERROR <> 0) BEGIN
    exec #HandleError
    -- If there was an error creating the sprocs, don't continue to the next batch
    RETURN
END

-- If compilation succeeded, then run the sproc
BEGIN TRY 
    exec #TEST
    RETURN
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    exec #HandleError
END CATCH;
```

Comment: So basically, if an object is renamed that a compiled sproc depends upon, the CATCH won't work. There may be workarounds, but basically the sproc needs fixing  to take account of the renamed object.

Comment: Yes, if your tables change, you should change any sprocs that point to them.  This doesn't allow your sproc to continue working, it just captures and logs the error, which may help in identifying cases where a sproc got missed and then doesn't fail until sometime later during runtime of the application.  I wouldn't say I'd recommend this for all of your stored procedures, but it works for this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I used THROW in my CATCH block before the INSERT statement for my logging - and got the same issue as you. Once I moved THROW after the logging INSERT statement it worked. Looks like THROW might terminate the session.

You don't use THROW in your code example, but thought this might help someone else.

Answer (score -1):

It's your RETURN: "Exits unconditionally from a query or procedure. RETURN is immediate and complete and can be used at any point to exit from a procedure, batch, or statement block."

Comment: The `RETURN` isn't being reached, as indicated by the `"Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."` error...

Comment: Thanks Russell - though I agree with Michael, I'm fairly certain Return isn't being reached. 

Thanks all for help on this - I think Ivan has the answer above.