# Why does TRY CATCH successfully update rows on SSMS but not when run from Tomcat application?

Tags: java, sql-server, error-handling

I have a TSQL procedure, on SQL for Azure. Here is a minimal reproducible example.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyPROC
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT 1/0
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        UPDATE error_log SET error_desc='test'
    END CATCH
END
```

When run directly from SSMS, then `error_log` is successfully updated.

When run from my Tomcat application (using the Tomcat user) then the procedure is executed but `error_log` is not updated.

Tomcat executes the procedure using the following Java code

```
    DBConnection dbConn  = DBConnection.getInstance();
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = dbConn.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{CALL MyPROC}");
        stmt.execute();
        result = stmt.getInt(fields.size());
        if (result == DBProcedures.RESULT_FAILED) { // error
            conn.rollback();
        } else { // ok
            conn.commit();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        result = DBProcedures.RESULT_FAILED;
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            System.out.println("Exception on " + this.toString() + " " + e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Exception on " + this.toString() + " " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            conn.setAutoCommit(true);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception on " + this.toString() + " " + e.toString());
        }
        dbConn.returnConnection(conn);
    }
```

I have checked that the Tomcat user has permissions on the `error_log` table.

What am I missing? I understand that [not all errors are caught by `TRY CATCH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092479/try-and-catch-on-tsql-catch-not-catching)  and I understand that sometimes the transaction [cannot execute any Transact-SQL statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) that would generate a write operation. However my example does not seem to fall under either of these two categories. Further it does work under SSMS.

Comment: Include the actual application code you are running (in Tomcat).

Comment: Thanks @Larnu. I added the Java code run from Tomcat

Comment: What's your connection string/settings for Tomcat? Do you have `autocommit` on or off?

Comment: Fire up the profiler

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface. I added more of the Java code. `autocommit` is off.

Comment: Set `autocommit` to on, then it will work the same as SSMS

Comment: If `autocommit` is off, where are you committing the changes?

Comment: @Larnu. I have added more Java code to show where I am committing the changes.

Comment: @Charlieface. Thanks. You have answered my original question. If you post this as an answer I will accept it. As a follow-up, is there any SQL code that I could add to the TSQL which will commit despite being called with `autocommit` being off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that `auto_commit` is set to off, which means that the driver executes the command [`SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

You can see this in action in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-ter_Nfi).

To get around it, you can explicitly rollback the original transaction first. You should also ideally use `XACT_ABORT` to prevent hanging transactions, and use `THROW;` to rethrow the original error.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE MyPROC
AS
BEGIN
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        SELECT 1/0;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK;

        UPDATE error_log SET error_desc = 'test';

        THROW;  -- only if you want the error to propagate back to Tomcat
    END CATCH;
END;
```

To be brutally honest, I do not recommend using `BEGIN CATCH` to log errors, as not all errors are catchable. Instead, use the SQL Server error log, or an XEvent session, to log errors.

Comment: Thank you for your fantastic answer, and also for the fiddle!